# Не работает проверка, является ли пользователь администратором php

Tags: php, sql

Есть следующая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со следующими записями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, пользователи, у которых по столбцу "admin" единица, являются администраторами, с нулём - нет.

Проверку осуществляю кодом:

```
<?php
    require "auth.php";
    $username = $_SESSION['login'];
    $admin = ("SELECT admin FROM loginparol WHERE login='$username'");
    $result = $connection->query ($admin);

    if ($admin == 0) {
        header('Location: MainPage.php');
        exit();
    }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["admin"]; //Сделал вывод, чтобы самому понимать, какое число в $admin передаётся, тут всё верно
        }
    }
```

Не работает проверка, пересылает на "MainPage.php" вообще всех без разбора. Если на написать не "== 0", а "!= 1", то вообще не работает. Я так понимаю, ошибка из-за того, что в if я неверно пишу условие. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно, сам не могу додуматься, изучаю php и SQL по ходу разработки проекта.

Comment: Вы хоть понимаете вообще, что делаете? У вас `$admin` - это строка запроса и вы ее с `0` сравниваете, конечно она будет равна. Так как приравнивается к типу `int`, чему будет и равна `0`. И инъекция обеспечена. Прочитайте про подготавливаемые запросы.

Comment: `if ($result->fetch_assoc()[0]["admin"] == 0) {` и нужно добавить проверку на существование этого массива, иначе если пользователя вообще нет - будет ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, спасибо пользователю And, который оставил комментарий, ткнул на ошибку и объяснил, где искать ответ. Переделал код вот так:

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $admin1= $row["admin"] ;
        }
    }

    if ($admin1 == 0) {
        header('Location: MainPage.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Суть ошибки в том, что я изначально сравнивал с нулём сам запрос. Для того, чтобы работало всё так, как я задумал, значение запроса нужно было передать в какую-то переменную. Что я и сделал в исправленной версии кода. Надеюсь, какому-нибудь новичку, как я, этот ответ поможет.

Comment: подойдет тип `tinyint(1)`